# Finding the maximum cardinality of a set

Tags: optimization, contest-math

Let $B$ be a subset of $A$ such that for any two elements $b_1$ and $b_2$ in $B$, we always have $2b_1\not \equiv{0}\pmod{b_2}$ if $2b_1\ge b_2$. If $A=\{1,2,...,n\}$ then find the maximum possible value of $|B|$.

So far I found that $\text{max}(|B|)\le\frac{n}{2}$ when $n$ is even and $\frac{n+1}{2}$ when $n$ is odd. But this was only by listing out a few values. Is there a rigorous way to find the maxima?

Edit: Maybe for $n>3$ it is $\pi(n)$ where $\pi(k)$ is the number of primes $p$ such that $2\le p \le k$.

Comment: Do you mean we always have $b_2\nmid 2b_1$ **if** $2b_1>b_2$ or $b_2\nmid 2b_1$ **and** $2b_1>b_2$ ?

Comment: ^Sorry it is meant to be 'if'

Comment: Are you assuming implicitly that $b_1 \neq b_2$?

Comment: yes b_1 and b_2 are distinct